# Retrieve a tag in a stdClass Object with php

Tags: php, instagram, stdclass

I am trying to retrieve the `[followed_by]` tag with this code. But it doesn't work.

--
instagram returns :

```
 stdClass Object
(
  [meta] => stdClass Object
    (
        [code] => 200
    )

[data] => stdClass Object
    (
        [username] => kenzasmg
        [bio] => Based in Paris | Twitter : @KenzaSMG | Facebook : La Revue de Kenza | Snapchat ðŸ‘» : KenzaSMG | kenzasmg@gmail.com
        [website] => http://larevuedekenza.fr/
        [profile_picture] => https://instagramimages-a.akamaihd.net/profiles/profile_3169582_75sq_1365288071.jpg
        [full_name] => Kenza  Sadoun - El Glaoui
        [counts] => stdClass Object
            (
                [media] => 5144
                [followed_by] => 76722
                [follows] => 250
            )

        [id] => 3169582
    )

)
```

---

My php code :

```
$result = $instagram->getUser(3169582);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '<pre>';

foreach ($result->data as $data) {

$followed = $data->counts->followed_by;
}

print($followed);
```

Comment: What does doesn't work mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi there. It looks like you have an implicit question in here. It's better for those answering you and for posterity if you can formulate a specific question, rather than simply stating that something "doesn't" work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($result->data as $data)
```

gives you [username], [bio]...[counts] .. So, you can't ask `data->counts->followed_by;`
Try so :

```
$followed = $result->data->counts->followed_by;
```